# Ajax call returns data with "/n" tags

Tags: ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hey All I've been searching around for awhile and haven't much luck finding the reasoning behind this so hopefully somebody can help me. I don't understand why it is returning newline characters

```
$('#tbl tr td').click(function () {

// Here selection ="           710-610A      "  spaces are included 
             var selection = $(this).text();
             alert(selection)

            $.ajax({                     
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "/Home/Index/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {  grpCode: selection },
                    success: function (ResponseData) {},
                    error: function (errorResponse) {
                    alert('AJAX Call Failed');
                }

 // When passed grpCode = "\n                  710-610A\n          "
   I dnt understand why theres so many spaces along with it 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string grpCode)
    {                    
        // do something
    }
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the way I'm displaying my table in the View

```
 <table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Groups
        </th>
    </tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model.groupCodesList.Select(m=> m.Group_Code).Distinct())
  {
      <tr>
          <td>
              @item
           </td>
      </tr>
  }
</table>
```

I am using EF Code First to retrieve Data

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding .trim() to my text

```
$('#tbl tr td').click(function () {
         var selection = $(this).text().trim();
         alert(selection)
```

Does anybody know why this was an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The contents of

```
          <td>
              @item
          </td>
```

is

```
"
              @item
          "
```

(as a multi-line string literal)

Normally, in HTML, the whitespace is mainly ignored, but they're still part of the content. They have to be, you could be using CSS's `white-space` to make them visible (like `<pre>`). So when you use JQuery's `.text()`, you get the full contents, including seemingly redundant whitespace.

If you make sure there is no whitespace in the first place,

```
<td>@item</td>
```

no extra whitespace will get inserted.